# How to check if UITextFields are empty?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a bunch of UITextFields where a user must enter a number (the keyboard is the number pad) before pressing a submit button. When the submit button is pressed, a "check" method is called that wants to check if the data is valid... aka not empty. Now this would be easy if it was just one textField but I have 14. I want a simple if-statement that checks if one of the fields or all of the fields are empty....

I have the follow UITextFields declared: number1, number2, number3 etc etc
and I have the follow strings declared which can take the value of the UITextField.text... they are declared: temp1, temp2, temp3 etc...

how would I go about making a pseudocode if statement like the one below?

Thanks

```
 if (!valid)
 {

NSLog (@"not valid)
} 

 else
{
 //proceed to next method
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I am supposing UITextField variable as ***tfield** so here is the solution

```
if (tfield.text.length > 0 || tfield.text != nil || ![tfield.text isEqual:@""])
{
   //do your work
}
else
{
   //through error
}
```

Comment: How would this work since not all my UITextField variables can be named *tfield? Thanks

Comment: textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)tfield use this delegate function  nad put the above code in it to check after user presses return button

Comment: This should be using && instead or ||

Answer (score 10):

or you could just call

```
[myTextField hasText];
```

which will return NO if the field is empty.

Answer (score 7):

I think something like this is what you want. It's just using `isEqualToString:` to check if the string is empty.

```
NSString *temp1 = number1.text;
NSString *temp2 = number2.text;
... ///< temp3, etc

if ([temp1 isEqualToString:@""]) {
    // temp1 not valid
} else if ([temp2 isEqualToString:@""]) {
    // temp2 not valid
} ... {
    // temp3, etc
} else {
    // Valid
}
```

You may want to trim whitespace characters when grabbing `temp1` so that `@"  "` would also be blank. For that, take a look at `NSString`'s `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:` method like so:

```
NSString *temp1 = [number1.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

**Update:**

If you want to do it with an array you could do something like:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
[array addObject:number1.text];
[array addObject:number2.text];
... ///< number3, etc

BOOL ok = YES;
[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([obj isEqualToString:@""]) {
        ok = NO;
        *stop = YES;
    }
}];

if (ok) {
    // Valid
} else {
    // Not valid
}
```

Comment: Thanks but not what I had in mind... is there a more simply way such as maybe putting all of them into an array and then checking if the array contains an empty string?

Comment: Not that would be much quicker than writing out that. You'd have to loop through the array and see if any of the strings are empty. Depends a bit on how many you've got.

Comment: @Teddy13 added an array way of doing it if you really want that.

Comment: One thing to note is that when using the `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];` approach, it is likely better to use the `whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet` character set as this will prevent a false positive when a blank line is the only content in the textfield.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would iterate through your UITextFields:

```
[self.view.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
  if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
     // do your checks
  }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you can put like this


    if(![temp1 isEqualToString:@""] && ![temp2 isEqualToString:@""] ... ![temp14 isEqualToString:@""])
    {
    NSLog (@" valid);
    }
    else
    {NSLog (@"not valid);
}
```

Comment: Isn't that the wrong way round? If all are not equal to `@""` then it's valid.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift,

You can use this block of code.

```
if textField.text?.isEmpty {

  //Return true if the textfield is empty or false if it's not empty.

}
```